# Remove black diamond chracter from string in JavaScript angular

Tags: javascript

Can some one please help me on this below string, I want to remove that dimond question mark from this string
I have tried in multiple ways but I am unable to identify this
question mark in string to remove.
This chracter could be place in starting or ending or middle of the string.

�漢字汉字

Comment: `s.replaceAll('�', '')`. With the caveat that Java and JavaScript are not the same thing; please consider tagging with only the language in question. The *actual* question is probably more along the lines of "what are legitimate character ranges of traditional and simplified Chinese characters" or something, but it's hard to say what *exactly* you need to replace (and why).

Comment: Dave Newton , thanks for your response,

Comment: I have tried above replace all but it's unable to identify that charcter in any string could you please help on this to remove that particular chracter from string,  this is appearing because of multibyte charcter